# Add Service Reference Link is not showing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I am unable to view the add service reference view. I have tried installing visual studio and re-installing it again, But the problem is persistent. Below is the image.

[image]

Comment: Do you see it in any other project type, like console app?

Comment: No, This option is not available in any type of project.

Comment: is it express, standard, ultimate or anything else?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219 SP1Rel. I have professional version.